# jQuery: How to AJAXify WordPress Search?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, search

I am trying to add AJAX functionality to a WordPress-based site.

When a visitor clicks a menu link, this code loads the text of the text of the required page into the main page:

```
$('#access a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#content').load(url, function() {
        $('#content').fadeIn(500);
        }); 
    });
});
```

My problem is with the search form. It has the following structure in the page:

```
<div id="my_search"><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://myurl.com/" >
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
    </form></div>
```

When I type a word testing into the form, and click the #searchsubmit" button or Enter key on the keyboard, I am redirected to a new WordPress page with the following address:

http://www.myurl.com/?s=testing

Here's PHP code that makes it work:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyten' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
                <?php
                /* Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                 * called loop-search.php and that will be used instead.
                 */
                 get_template_part( 'loop', 'search' );
                ?>
<?php else : ?>
                <div id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyten' ); ?></h2>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'twentyten' ); ?></p>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </div><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

**QUESTION: I want to prevent the default behavior on #searchsubmit click and on Enter key click, and load the content of the search results (http://www.myurl.com/?s=whateverwordItype) into the #content of the main page. How can I do that?**

(I suppose I just need to insert that php code inside jQuery code in some way, but the task is a little beyond my knowledge of jQuery and PHP.)

I would be grateful for a code snippet from a knowledgeable person, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

### Use some simple jQuery and javascript

In order to load your search results through an ajax request you can grab them directly from the search results page using the following code:

```
// Bind the submit event for your form
$('#searchform').submit(function( e ){ 

    // Stop the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the search term
    var term = $('#s').val();

    // Make sure the user searched for something
    if ( term ){

        $.get( '/', { s: term }, function( data ){

            // Place the fetched results inside the #content element
            $('#content').html( $(data).find('#content') );

        });

    }

});
```

Note: `$(data).find('#content')` is assuming your `search.php` results aggregate in an element whose id is content i.e. `<div id="#content"> ... Results ... </div>`

The above would go into an external file or placed just before the closing `</body>` tag.

You can customize the `search.php` page to organize your output results.

Comment: Thanks! Wish I had that kind of answer back a year and a half ago when I actually asked the question, but better late than never!

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov SO is a kind of Q&A wikipedia so anyone that comes along with this question will have an answer, even if it is a year old question.

Comment: I agree, and your answer is just what I was looking for, except I wish  you posted it back in 2011 when I needed it so badly! :-)

Comment: I am getting this error data is not defined, how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#searchsubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var search_val=$("#s").val(); 
    $.post('search.php',{search_string:search_val},function(data){
        if(data.length>0){
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
      });
});
```

This will call the search.php, which will get the search string as a post variable like `$_POST['search_string']`, Here, you process the search string and echo the results, which will be get back to the page as `data`. Have a div with id day `results`, The `$("#results").html(data);` will put the results got from search.php into the div. If you want to use get, then just replace post in the jQuery funstion as get and you can use `$_GET[]`in the search.php.

Hope this would help you

Comment: Balanivash, you are definitely onto something. I think this is the correct direction. Somehow, it doesn't work. When I click the button, nothing happens at all, but still I think your approach should be correct. Could you please take a look at your code and see if there's a minor error in it that prevents it from working?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is not working for you, cos this is working perfectly fine for me. Try giving an alert inside the `click` function and similarly by giving break points in your code.

Comment: Tried it. No luck. The button just doesn't do anything. Still, I'm quite sure that yours is the correct decision, Balanivash – I just can;t figure out why it's not working on my end.  Could you take a look at my source code please? http://cybart.com/bscg/

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem with nothing happening when the results are shown. Wish it did because this would be perfect.

Comment: Do you guys have an element with the id "results" in your html? If not, there's no where to put the results data.