# jQuery: Load a PHP Snippet

Tags: php, jquery, load

I use this code to load the content from a different page into the main page:

```
$('#access a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#content').load(url, function() {
        $('#content').fadeIn(500);
        }); 
    });
});
```

I want to be able to load the output of `<?php /*my PHP code */ ?>` into the same container when #mybutton is clicked.

How can I do that?

I suspect it has to be something very basic, but I'm not sure how it's done. I would appreciate expertly advice!

**UPDATE: here's the bit of php code I'm trying to run:**

```
<?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyten' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php
                /* Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                 * called loop-search.php and that will be used instead.
                 */
                 get_template_part( 'loop', 'search' );
                ?>
<?php else : ?>
                <div id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyten' ); ?></h2>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'twentyten' ); ?></p>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </div><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand: you mean load the same page contents into the same container? If not, what snippet of PHP exactly? Where does it come from?

Comment: No Wizard, I mean i want to load the output of a certain php code into the container to replace the current content. It comes from the server, I suppose...

Comment: Think I got it, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it might be more simple than what you think.

First, wrap the PHP output with hidden `<div>`:

```
<div id="searchResults" style="display: none;">
<?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyten' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>
.....
.....
.....
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Then just copy those contents to the other container on button click:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#content').html($('#searchResults').html());
        $('#content').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

If I didn't understand correctly please explain better and I'll try to find other way around this.

Comment: This is quite brilliant actually, Shadow Wizard. I think this finally may be a correct solution, except as of now, something is still a little off. The search form ignores search words I type into it, and just duplicates the content of the current page. Could you help me to make it work, Wizard?

Comment: What is the code for `get_search_query()`? Where does it take the data from?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't figure it out so far. It's a wordpress command but I can't determine what's the addressee of it. One thing I noticed though, it seems to reflect whatever is in URL. For example, if the url would be mydomain.com/?s=testing, the search results would be for that word. Does it give you some idea what may be going on?

Comment: So sounds like you'll have to use AJAX, send such URL to the server on button click and parse the results. I understand now that you don't control the PHP page or code?

Comment: I can't even FIND the damn thing! :-) Here's what normally happens with WordPress: you type the word ('testing') in the searform, click the button, a new page opens with the url: mydomain.com/?s=testing - and that new page contains the search results. What I need it to somehow get those search results without opening the new page, and then load them into the page that is currently open. Here's the site I work on, by the way: http://www.cybart.com/bscg/ I'd be very grateful if you could help me figure out what can be done, Wizard.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with WordPress so don't have more ideas.. but does accepting the answer mean you found a way around?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mybutton').click(function()
{
    $('#content').load('place_where_your_php_code_is_at.php'); 
});
```

jQuery does DOM and AJAX, it doesn't execute PHP, so you would have to call a script return the HTML output and display it in your #content box.

Alternatively, you could do a hack-around (really unsafe stuff, because anybody can change your javascript from the console)
You could have a php file which has the [eval function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) and returns the execution, and then you can call it dynamically.  Like this,

```
$.get('php_executor.php', code='echo "hello world";', function (val) {
$('#content').html(val);
});
```

And your php would contain something in the lines of   `<? eval($_GET['code']); ?>`

I was just answering your question, I do not recommend using it because anybody could inject all kinds of unsecure code. However, If you plan using it only yourself, it might be worth a shot.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

PHP will be executed in the server side, so if you want to load a PHP snippet, then you need to request the server to give the output of the PHP snippet to you. For this you need to use AJAX. Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You can use the jQuery `.load`, `.ajax`, `.post` to do this

Comment: Balanivash, I think you're onto something. Could you please take a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677820/jquery-how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-search

Answer (score 1):

The way you've asked your question implies that you haven't fully understood the client-server nature of a web page, and the order in which parts of the code are run.

The solution to your problem is a technique called Ajax. It is extremely simple to do using JQuery.

In short, it allows you to make a fresh call to a new PHP call (or any other server-side code) from within your Javascript code, without having to reload the whole page; the response that comes from the PHP call is given to your Javascript instead of simply being loaded into the browser window as a new page. The Javascript code is then free to use it however it likes; often this means inserting it into the existing page as a new block of content -- which is basically what you're asking for.

There's a lot more to it than that; more I can explain in a short answer here: I suggest you investigate it. Google for "Jquery PHP Ajax tutorials", or similar, and I'm sure you'll come up with some helpful tips.

[EDIT] As request, an example:

In your Javascript code, you could have something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajaxtest.php",
          success: function(response_data){
            $('#my_container_div').html(response_data);
         }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id='my_button'>Click me</button>
<br /><br />
<div id='my_container_div'>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, you would need to have a button with id of 'my_button' and an element with id of 'my_container_div' in the page. This JQuery code will add a click event to the button such that when you click on it, the Ajax code is run.

The Ajax code calls your separate PHP program, and when that program returns some content (whatever that content happens to be), it will be displayed into the container div.

The PHP program is entirely separate from your main PHP program that generated the original page, and does not have access to any of its variables (other than session data of course). You can have this PHP code return anything you like. Usually it would be a snippet of HTML code, or a chunk of text. Often it is in the form of JSON code, which is an array that can be converted into Javascript variables. This allows you to share data between your PHP and Javascript environments.

As I said, this is a very large topic. There's lots more to it, but you'll need to investigate it for yourself. I hope this has helped get you started though.

**NB:** I have tested the above code. It works. You do obviously also need a PHP program that will generate some output.

Comment: Thank you Spudley. It's a great explanation, and it shows that you understand my question. That's exactly what I'm asking about! BUT: how do I do that? I would appreciate it if you could share a code snippet with me.

Comment: @Dimitri - as I said, it's a huge topic. I'll edit the question to include an example, but you will need to research it further for yourself.

Comment: Yeah, just as you said Sudley, it doesn't work. Experimented with it, no luck. Would appreciate a bit more help from you.

Comment: @Dimitri - the code I posted did work. It needed to be in a document ready block for JQuery's `click()` to work, but I assumed you knew that already. I've now tested it and I've edited it to give you the exact and complete code I used (excluding the PHP code, which could just be a `print "hello";` line, as long as it outputs something)

Comment: Thank you for testing it Spudley. Didn't work for me though. I do use document ready of course. I suspect there may be some sort of error in my php code that prevents your code from working. I'm posting the php code in the body of my question, could you please take a look?

Comment: @Dimitry - test it with the code above, linking to a plain text file instead of a PHP file. It does work.

Comment: Thank you Spudley. Tested it with plain text. Doesn't work on my end. I am adding something to your code, I suspect that's the culprit, event though I don't see why it would disable the code. Here's my version that doesn't work: $('#searchsubmit').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: "mysearch.txt",
          success: function(response_data){
            $('#container').html(response_data);
         }
        });
    }); Do you think event.preventDefault(); could cause the problem?

Comment: @Dimitri - yes, it possibly could be. Perhaps you're getting to the point where you should be starting a brand new question on SO, as your original question was answered a long time ago, and we've moved a long way since then.

Comment: Yeah Spudley, the question was answered actually several times, the problem is, the answers kinda don't work. BUT - I did ask the question, just as you suggested. Perhaps you could take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677820/jquery-how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-search

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e){
    $('#content').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#content').load('urlOfYourPHP', function() {
            $('#content').fadeIn(500);
        }); 
    });


}
```

EDIT:

//this should put whatever your php returns into #content, BUT it won't re-run the php every time, it'll be rendered with the rest of the page/

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e){
    $('#content').html('<?php /*my PHP code */ ?>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Patricia. Is there any way to do it without URL? Just directly plug PHP code into jQuery?

Comment: ahhh,  see what you mean, does the php render html? i've got an idea.

Comment: the PHP enables the search form. What I'm trying to achieve it to load search results into the main page.

Comment: Thank you Patricia, let me try that!

Comment: in that case, your going to have to have that php as a separate page that returns your search results, and pass the url to load, like my original answer shows.

Comment: Thank you Patricia - here's the question though. Let's say, the page's url is search.php. But the url of the search results shown on that page is myurl.com/s?=whateverwordI'mserachingfor. How do I address that dynamic url in the jQuery code?

Comment: Patricia, I tried the solution you recommended, but it just reloads the content of the same page. Could you further help please?

Comment: well, of course it is, if the php is the same as what generates your page.

you need to be a little more clear on what exactly your trying to do!

Comment: Actually, the php code whose output I am trying to load with your code is quite different. But - could you take a look at this question please, Patricia: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677820/jquery-how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-search